# Partial or fuzzy match in R

Tags: r

I want to do fuzzy match on 2 dataframes (s1 is data and s2 is reference) based on the 'Answer' column inorder to get corresponding question count and category from s2 .
Ex:

```
s1 <- data.frame(Category =c("Stationary","TransferRelocationClaim","IMS"),
Question =c( "Where do I get stationary items from?","Process for claiming Transfer relocation allowances.","What is IMS?"),Answer = c("Hey <firstname>, you will find it near helpdesk ","Hey <firstname>, moving to new places can be fun! To claim relocation expense please follow the steps given below- 1. request you to add the code in https://portal.mycompany.com ,enter relocation code ,add. 2. select expenses ,add expense ,other expense ,fill the form ,save ,print (select the print icon).","ims or interview management system is a tool that helps interviewers schedule all the interviews"),
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

s2 <- data.frame(
Question = c("Where to get books?", "Procedure to order stationary?","I would like to know about my relocation and relocation expenses","tell me about relocation expense claiming","how to claim relocation expense","IMS?"),
Answer = c("Hey Anil, you will find it at the helpdesk.", "Hey, Shekhar, you will find it at the helpdesk.", "hey sonali moving to new places can be fun! to claim relocation expense please follow the steps given below- 1. request you to add the code in https://portal.mycompany.com ,enter relocation code ,add. 2. select expenses ,add expense ,other expense ,fill the form ,save ,print (select the print icon)","hey piyush moving to new places can be fun! to claim relocation expense please follow the steps given below- 1. request you to add the code in https://portal.mycompany.com ,assignments ,enter relocation code ,add. 2. select expenses ,add expense ,other expense ,fill the form ,save ,print (select the print icon). 3. attach the bills to the printout and secure approval sign-off / mail (from the pa support for new joinee relocation claims and the portal approver for existing employees). 4. drop the bills in the portal drop box (the duty manager amp, finance team can confirm the coordinates.", "hey vibha moving to new places can be fun! to claim relocation expense please follow the steps given below- 1. request you to add the code in https://portal.mycompany.com ,assignments ,enter relocation code ,add. 2. select expenses ,add expense ,other expense ,fill the form ,save ,print (select the print icon). 3. attach the bills to the printout and secure approval sign-off / mail from the pa support for new joinee relocation claims and the portal approver for existing employees). 4. drop the bills in the portal drop box (the duty manager amp, finance team can confirm the coordinates", "ims or interview management system is a tool that helps interviewers schedule all the interviews")
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

s1$Response=gsub('[[:punct:] ]+',' ',s1$Response)
s2$Response=gsub('[[:punct:] ]+',' ',s2$Response)
s1$Response <- tolower(s1$Response)
s2$Response <- tolower(s2$Response)
s1$Response<-as.character(s1$Response)
s2$Response<-as.character(s2$Response)
# data =s1, lookup=s2
d.matrix <- stringdistmatrix(a = s2$Response, b = s1$Response, useNames="strings",method="cosine", nthread = getOption("sd_num_thread"))

#list of minimun cosines
cosines<-apply(d.matrix, 2, min)

#return list of the row number of the minimum value
minlist<-apply(d.matrix, 2, which.min) 

#return list of best matching values
matchwith<-s2$Response[minlist]

#below table contains best match and cosines
answer<-data.frame(s1$Response, matchwith, cosines)
t11=merge(x=answer,y=s2, by.x="matchwith", by.y="Response", all.x=TRUE)
View(t11)`
```

[image: t11 table looks like as shown below]
    Next, I have to get count of s1.Response = 3 for Question : Process for claiming Transfer relocation allowances? along with Category name. Kindly guide me as to how it can be done.

Comment: Please add reproducible sample data (e.g. using `dput`) instead of describing what the data looks like. Adding your expected output often helps with understanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi, I have added sample output for better understanding.

Comment: I cannot figure out what rules you are assuming we will intuit from teh input and output. You need to describe the process in more detail. If you simply want us to invent some sort of natural language processing algorithm, then the question is too broad, but at the moment I'm going to assume you have a specific set of rules in mind and will only vote to close as currently unclear.

Comment: I have two dataframes s1, s2: where first table is a reference table, and second one is another one, from which I need to get counts of Answers for each Question asked in reference file. I need to do fuzzy match on Answer column on both the dataframes. Also, get corresponding question from reference file.

Comment: @Sand *"i have added sample output for better understanding"* This is *not* a good format; please use `dput` on a representative subsample of your two `data.frame`s. Still missing your expected output too.

Comment: @Sand PS. You've been an SO member for nearly 2 years. I would expect you to know how to provide a reproducible minimal example, including (1) reproducible and copy&paste-able sample data, (2) a clear problem statement and (3) any code attempt (you mention cosine similarity) and expected output.

Comment: Honestly, Sand, I think what you are asking is clear: you want a NLP solution that can loosely match questions and therefore merge in the answers to the similar-enough questions. I'm not an expert on NLP, so I think I'm out on that alone, sorry. However, you've provided no coding effort and it something else that seems clear to me is that you want somebody else to either (1) do all the work for you *for free*, or perhaps (2) *"recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial"* (quoted from the list of [off-topic questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)).

Comment: Sure, I will update shortly with the code. Just putting it in required format.

Answer (score 0):

You could try matching using the `agrepl` function which lets you set a maximum "distance" which is the sum of "transformations needed to go from a pattern to a target. I would take out the material around the flanking angle brackets with `sub`:

```
agrepl(sub("<.+>, ", "", df1$Answer), df2$Answer, 8)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

(Note: teh FALSE comes from my having modified the second dataframe so that it had a non-matching "answer" value.

Answer (score 0):

If we slightly modify your first input we can use packages *`fuzzyjoin`/`dplyr`/`stringr`* the following way :

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  Category = "Stationary",
  Question = "Where do I get stationary items from?",
  Answer = "Hey <firstname>, you will find it <here>.", # <-notice the change!
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

df2 <- data.frame(
    Category = c("Stat1", "Stat1"),
    Question = c("Where to get books?", "Procedure to order stationary?"),
    Answer = c("Hey Anil, you will find it at the helpdesk.", "Hey, Shekhar, you will find it at the helpdesk."),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
```

We make a regex pattern from `Answer` :

```
df1 <- dplyr::mutate(
  df1,
  Answer_regex =gsub("([.|()\\^{}+$*?]|\\[|\\])", "\\\\\\1", Answer), # escape special
  Answer_regex = gsub(" *?<.*?> *?",".*?", Answer_regex), # replace place holders by .*?
  Answer_regex = paste0("^",Answer_regex,"$"))  # make sure the match is exact
```

We use `stringr::str_detect` with `fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_left_join` to find matches :

```
res <- fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_left_join(df2, df1, by= c(Answer="Answer_regex"), match_fun = stringr::str_detect )
res
#   Category.x                     Question.x                                        Answer.x Category.y
# 1      Stat1            Where to get books?     Hey Anil, you will find it at the helpdesk. Stationary
# 2      Stat1 Procedure to order stationary? Hey, Shekhar, you will find it at the helpdesk. Stationary
#                              Question.y                                  Answer.y                     Answer_regex
# 1 Where do I get stationary items from? Hey <firstname>, you will find it <here>. ^Hey.*?, you will find it.*?\\.$
# 2 Where do I get stationary items from? Hey <firstname>, you will find it <here>. ^Hey.*?, you will find it.*?\\.$
```

Then we can count:

```
dplyr::count(res,Answer.y)
# # A tibble: 1 x 2
#          Answer.y                               n
#          <chr>                              <int>
# 1 Hey <firstname>, you will find it <here>.     2
```

Note that I included spaces outside of `<` and `>` as part of the placeholders. If I didn't do this `"Hey, Shekhar"` wouldn't have been matched, because of the comma.

---

edit to address comment :

```
df1 <- dplyr::mutate(df1, Answer_trimmed = gsub("<.*?>", "", Answer))
res <- fuzzy_left_join(df2, df1, by= c(Answer="Answer_trimmed"), 
                       match_fun = function(x,y) stringdist::stringdist(x, y) / nchar(y) < 0.7)
#   Category.x                     Question.x                                        Answer.x Category.y
# 1      Stat1            Where to get books?     Hey Anil, you will find it at the helpdesk. Stationary
# 2      Stat1 Procedure to order stationary? Hey, Shekhar, you will find it at the helpdesk.       <NA>
#                              Question.y                                Answer.y               Answer_trimmed
# 1 Where do I get stationary items from? Hey <firstname>, you will find it here. Hey , you will find it here.
# 2                                  <NA>                                    <NA>                         <NA>


dplyr::count(res,Answer.y)
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   Answer.y                                    n
#   <chr>                                   <int>
# 1 <NA>                                        1
# 2 Hey <firstname>, you will find it here.     1
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I tried it. For answers having exact match after the name of the person, it works. However, if count of partial match is also needed, what changes are required?

Comment: for this we need a definition of what makes a partial match, @42's answer and `?agrepl` might help. See also package `stringdist` and package `fuzzyjoin` with its specific joins on string distance.

Comment: Hi, wherever, answer is 60 or 70% matching, you are suggesting to replace with  <here>." as mentioned by you in code above, inorder to get counts.

Comment: after merging, we need count of answer as 2 for question where do i get stationary items from

Comment: You can play with the parameter I have set to 0.7, or investigate other distance metrics, I just made one up as you didn't specify a precise metric.

Comment: I have done using cosine similarity, however stuck towards the end, finding the count of s1.Response for questions in s2

Comment: you changed the names of variables from df to s and it seems you changed mid way from Answer to Response.

Comment: You did something totally different now, I think you'd have your answer if you just use `method = "cosine"` in my `stringdist` call and choose a relevant treshold.

Comment: I have to get count of s1.Response = 3 for Question : Process for claiming Transfer relocation allowances? along with Category name. Kindly guide me as to how it can be done from the code written on the top.

Comment: Hi all, can anyone please suggest as to how to get count of s1.Response = 3 for Question : Process for claiming Transfer relocation allowances?Please refer the updated code written on the top.