# Combining rows using fuzzy matching of the keys in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I have a data set that might contain some very similar keys - something like a row of data for each of the email address `john.doe@foo.com` and `john.m.doe@foo.com`. How can I combine similarly named keys and do an aggregate in R?

Sample input

```
|Email              | Subscriptions |
-------------------------------------
|john.doe@foo.com   | 10            |
|john.m.doe@foo.com | 11            |
|jane.doe@foo.com   | 20            |
```

Expected result

```
|Email              | Subscriptions |
-------------------------------------
|john.doe@foo.com   | 21            |
|jane.doe@foo.com   | 20            |
```

I know `agrep` and few other libraries can do fuzzy matching, but how do I employ it in combining rows in a data set?

Comment: Does your data have any columns such as ID,..?

Comment: @ThoVu No ID columns.

Comment: Check out this answer which uses fuzzy matching https://stackoverflow.com/a/55296616/8535855, not your exact problem, but a similar approach?

Comment: The fuzzyjoin package mentioned in the link from @RussThomas also allows matching by string distance metrics which might give you more potential to set it to your specific needs

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to use `agrep` in combination with `dplyr`:

```
df <- data.frame(mail = c("john.doe@foo.com", "john.m.doe@foo.com", "jane.doe@foo.com"),
                 sub = c(10, 11, 20))

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(new = paste(agrep(mail, df$mail, max = 2, ignore.case = TRUE), collapse = ",")) %>%
  group_by(new) %>% 
  mutate(sub = sum(sub)) %>%
  slice(1) 


  mail               sub new  
  <fct>            <dbl> <chr>
1 john.doe@foo.com    21 1,2  
2 jane.doe@foo.com    20 3
```

Comment: This won't really cluster the addresses - the same `mail` can end up in different clusters. Try adding `"jon.doe@foo.com"` to `df` and see what happens.